# Add Button on my View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm creating a hidden form containing 3 buttons at the bottom of the parent view, by pressing another button, the view becomes visible, but those 3 buttons are not pressed, I don `t know what the problem is.

I add a button via code. Here is a method that is called when the button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction) addData:(id)sender
```

{

```
    if(attachInfo==nil){
        float screenHeight =  self.view.frame.size.height;
        attachInfo=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight, 320, 216)];



        UIButton *attachImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //attachImage.enabled = YES;
        [attachImage addTarget:self action:@selector(addImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [attachImage setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 0, 0)];
        [attachImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_photos"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attachImage sizeToFit];
        [attachInfo addSubview:attachImage];



        UIButton *attachDoc = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[pushButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [attachDoc setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 80, 80)];
        [attachDoc setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_docs.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attachDoc sizeToFit];
        [attachInfo addSubview:attachDoc];

        UIButton *attachPlace = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[pushButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [attachPlace setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 20, 80, 80)];
        [attachPlace setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_place.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [attachPlace sizeToFit];
        [attachInfo addSubview:attachPlace];

        //[self.view addSubview:attachInfo];
        [self.view addSubview:attachInfo];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            CGRect frame = attachInfo.superview.frame;
            frame.origin.y -= 216;
            attachInfo.superview.frame=frame;
        }];






    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            CGRect frame = attachInfo.superview.frame;
            frame.origin.y += 216;
            attachInfo.superview.frame=frame;
        }];
        attachInfo=nil;
    }



}
```

Comment: show us some code to work on ;)

Comment: Please post  your code for displaying that view.Whether you add those buttons in coding or in xib? Explain clearly.

Comment: post code wht u tried ?

Comment: Not only code but make ur Question clear

Comment: does the buttons visible when the view becomes visible?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Action of buttons.

```
 - (IBAction)first:(id)sender;
    {

    firstViewController * fvc=[FirstViewController alloc]init];

   [FirstButton setHidden:False];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];




    }
    - (IBAction)Second:(id)sender;
    {

    SecondViewController * svc=[SecondViewController alloc]init];


   [SecondButton setHidden:False]; 

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

    }
    - (IBAction)Third:(id)sender;
    {

    ThirdViewController * tvc=[ThirdViewController alloc]init];

   [ThirdButton setHidden:False];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: On buttons are hanging methods.

Comment: He doesn't want to fire any method. He just want to enable button to click..?

Comment: check your xib your outlet and IBAction connection are properly Connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the first button (attachImage), the height and the width is zero. So it should not be visible. For the other two buttons you haven't set the target. So those are not clickable.

for the first button set

```
 [attachImage setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80)];
```

and for the other two buttons add

```
//for the second button
[attachDoc addTarget:self action:@selector(addImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//for the third button
[attachPlace addTarget:self action:@selector(addImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Have you change the frame size and add those targets to your other two buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)createHiddenForm
 {
     hiddenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320,300)];
     [hidden setHidden:TRUE];

     [self.view addSubview:hiddenView];

     float posY = 50.0;

     for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
     {
         UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [button setFrame:CGRectMake(50,posY, 100, 50)];
         [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [hiddenView addSubview:button];

         posY=posY+60;
     }
 }

 -(void)showHiddenView
 {
       hidden.hidden = FALSE;
       [self.view bringSubviewToFront:hiddenView];
 }

 -(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
 {
       UIButton *senderBtn = (UIButton *)sender;

       NSLog(@"Sender Button's tag = %@",senderBtn.tag);
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
float screenHeight =  self.view.frame.size.height;
attachInfo=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight, 320, 216)];
```

From the above, u r adding the attachInfo Y position outside the view boundaries. 
Button onclick won't work when added outside the view.

To make it work replace below line.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        CGRect frame = attachInfo.superview.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= 216;
        attachInfo.superview.frame=frame;
```

Instead of moving superview frame move attachInfo frame like this.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        CGRect frame = attachInfo.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= 216;
        attachInfo.frame=frame;
```

So that attachInfo view will be added to the super view boundaries with animation.

Comment: How to make that work? I'm creating a view outside of the screen, add buttons and scrollView, and move it with animation block, superview on top. But none of the elements is not working((